# Открытие - закрытие блоков. При открытии второго блока, первый незакрывается

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы при отображении одного скрытого блока, и нажатии на другой, тот что был открыт ранее  - закрывался. Нажал на другой, предыдущий скрылся, открылся другой и т.д

```js
 var block1 = document.getElementById('block1');
 var content1 = document.getElementById('content1');
 var link1 = block1.querySelector('.title');
  link1.onclick = function() {
      content1.classList.toggle('open');
    };
 
 
 var block2 = document.getElementById('block2');
 var content2 = document.getElementById('content2');
 var link2 = block2.querySelector('.title');
  link2.onclick = function() {
      content2.classList.toggle('open');
    };
 
 
  var block3 = document.getElementById('block3');
 var content3 = document.getElementById('content3');
 var link3 = block3.querySelector('.title');
  link3.onclick = function() {
      content3.classList.toggle('open');
    };
```

```css
   .block-content {
      display: none;
      
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }

    #block1 .title, #block2 .title, #block3 .title {
      font-size: 18px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    

    .block-content.open {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div id="block1">
    <span class="title">Физические лица</span>
</div>
<div class="block-content" id="content1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus consectetur esse est culpa voluptates dignissimos tempore blanditiis quidem quam tempora, quae iste nesciunt obcaecati quia quis consequuntur! Veritatis, in, quisquam!</div>  
  
<div id="block2">
    <span class="title">Юридические лица</span>
</div>
<div class="block-content" id="content2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus consectetur esse est culpa voluptates dignissimos tempore blanditiis quidem quam tempora, quae iste nesciunt obcaecati quia quis consequuntur! Veritatis, in, quisquam!</div>  


<div id="block3">
    <span class="title">Юридические лица (НДС 18%)</span>
</div>
<div class="block-content" id="content3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus consectetur esse est culpa voluptates dignissimos tempore blanditiis quidem quam tempora, quae iste nesciunt obcaecati quia quis consequuntur! Veritatis, in, quisquam!</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного подправить html, добавить `data-target="content1"`

```
        <div id="block1">
        <span class="title" data-target="content1">Физические лица</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content" id="content1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus consectetur esse est culpa voluptates dignissimos tempore blanditiis quidem quam tempora, quae iste nesciunt obcaecati quia quis consequuntur! Veritatis, in, quisquam!</div>  

        <div id="block2">
        <span class="title" data-target="content2">Юридические лица</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content" id="content2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus consectetur esse est culpa voluptates dignissimos tempore blanditiis quidem quam tempora, quae iste nesciunt obcaecati quia quis consequuntur! Veritatis, in, quisquam!</div>  


        <div id="block3">
        <span class="title" data-target="content3">Юридические лица (НДС 18%)</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content" id="content3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus consectetur esse est culpa voluptates dignissimos tempore blanditiis quidem quam tempora, quae iste nesciunt obcaecati quia quis consequuntur! Veritatis, in, quisquam!</div>
```

И изменить скрипт

```
        var clicked = '' //переменная для сохранения закрывающегося элемента
        document.addEventListener('click', e => { //можно вешать и не на документ
            const targetId = e.target.getAttribute('data-target') || '' // достаем id элемента
            if(!targetId) return // если его нет, выходим из скрипта
            const target = document.getElementById(targetId) // ссылка на сам элемент
            if(clicked && clicked !== target) clicked.classList.remove('open') 
            //если это не первое открытие и не 2ой раз открывается текущий, то скрываем
            target.classList.add('open')
            clicked = target //сохраняем ссылку в замыкании
        })
```

Comment: У вас в примере есть => . Это стрелочная функция ES16? Если да, то функционал не будет работать в относительно старых браузерах, да?

Comment: Можете заменить " e =>" на "function (e)", и const на var, если хотите что бы ваш код поддерживали динозавры